React app error: ENOENT No such file or directory "../node_modules/.cache"
Almost after every time I save my react project, I get the error below, causing me to have to re-enter "npm start" manually. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
/Users/directory/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/directory/node_modules/.cache/default-development/10.pack'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/directory/node_modules/.cache/default-development/10.pack'
}

